# Ubuntu One Promotion

Tags: ubuntu-one

It says on the website that if we buy any music track from the ubuntu store,
we'll get free music streaming for six months + 20GB of free storage.

I know that the music streaming service will expire after six months if we don't intend 
on continuing it, but does the 20GB of storage expire too unless we continue to pay?

Answer (score 2):

> When your music streaming subscription expires, your account will be
>   reverted back to the free 5GB of storage.

Source: [Ubuntu One Help FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-happens-when-my-music-streaming-subscription-expires/)