# 20 GB space offer

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Promotion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210948/ubuntu-one-promotion)

There is an offer which says

> Buy any track from the new Ubuntu One Music Store and get 6 months Music Streaming + 20GB storage free!

Is the 20GB space time limited?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 20 GB is part of the music streaming plan. It expires after that 6 months if you don't purchase streaming.